# problem with the synthasizable version of vivado hls

Tags: c++, opencv, vivado, vivado-hls

i am implementing a simple image transformation filter in vivado hls. I have attached the files below:

```
//headerfile- ct_h.hpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <hls_stream.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windef.h>

#define MAX_IMG_ROWS 1080
#define MAX_IMG_COLS 1920
#define MAX_IMG_CHANNELS 3
#define min_pix (float)0.0
#define max_pix (float)255.0
#define TEST_IMG_ROWS 256
#define TEST_IMG_COLS 512
#define TEST_IMG_CHANNELS 512

typedef unsigned char data_t;
void ct_filter(
        int w, int h,
        data_t input_image, data_t output_image,float TsTw_tran[3][3]);
```

synthasizable part:

```
//Mainfile - ct_core.cpp
//core
#include "ct_h.hpp"
#include <hls_math.h>


void ct_filter(int width, int height,
        data_t src[256][512][3], data_t dst[256][512][3],float TsTw_tran[3][3])
{


        float red_ar, green_ar, blue_ar;
            float red_new_ar, green_new_ar, blue_new_ar;


            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    red_ar = (((float)src[i][j][0]) / 256.0);
                    green_ar = (((float)src[i][j][1]) / 256.0);
                    blue_ar = (((float)src[i][j][2]) / 256.0);

                    red_new_ar = red_ar * TsTw_tran[0][0] + green_ar * TsTw_tran[1][0] + blue_ar * TsTw_tran[2][0];
                    green_new_ar = red_ar * TsTw_tran[0][1] + green_ar * TsTw_tran[1][1] + blue_ar * TsTw_tran[2][1];
                    blue_new_ar = red_ar * TsTw_tran[0][2] + green_ar * TsTw_tran[1][2] + blue_ar * TsTw_tran[2][2];

                    red_new_ar = red_new_ar*255.0;
                    green_new_ar = green_new_ar*255.0;
                    blue_new_ar = blue_new_ar*255.0;

                    red_new_ar = fmin(fmax(red_new_ar, min_pix), max_pix);
                    green_new_ar = fmin(fmax(green_new_ar, min_pix), max_pix);
                    blue_new_ar = fmin(fmax(blue_new_ar, min_pix), max_pix);

                    dst[i][j][0] = (data_t)red_new_ar;
                    dst[i][j][1] = (data_t)green_new_ar;
                    dst[i][j][2] = (data_t)blue_new_ar;
                }
            }


}
```

Testbenchpart:

```
//ct_testbench.cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "math.h"
#include <chrono>
#include "ct_h.hpp"
#include <hls_opencv.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
float TsTw_tran[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < TsTw_trans.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < TsTw_trans[i].size(); j++) {
                TsTw_tran[i][j] = TsTw_trans[i][j];
            }
        }//caluclated this from previous functions, code is not posted here

    //data_t * const input_img = new data_t[TEST_IMG_ROWS][TEST_IMG_COLS][TEST_IMG_CHANNELS];
    //data_t * const output_img = new data_t[TEST_IMG_ROWS][TEST_IMG_COLS][TEST_IMG_CHANNELS];
    data_t input_img[256][512][3];
    data_t output_img[256][512][3];
    Mat img_rev = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/output_rev.png");
    Mat final_img(img_rev.rows,img_rev.cols,CV_8UC3);

    Mat ideal = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/output_fwd_v4.png");
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_IMG_ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < TEST_IMG_COLS; j++)
            {
                input_img[i][j][0] = img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2];//R - B
                input_img[i][j][1] = img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1];//G - G
                input_img[i][j][2] = img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0];//B - R
            }
        }


    ct_filter(TEST_IMG_COLS, TEST_IMG_ROWS, input_img, output_img, TsTw_tran);

    for (int i = 0; i < img_rev.rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < img_rev.cols; j++)
            {
                final_img.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = output_img[i][j][0];//R
                final_img.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = output_img[i][j][1];//G
                final_img.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = output_img[i][j][2];//B

            }
        }
    imwrite("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/hls_gen_stage3.png",final_img);
return 0
}
```

The simulation part is giving me an correct result but when I try to synthesize this, I am getting these errors

```
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_storeups': 

C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\xmmintrin.h:630
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_movntps'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_movntss'?: C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\xmmintrin.h:678
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_cvtps2pd': C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\emmintrin.h:380
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_cvtdq2pd'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_cvtdq2ps'?: C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\emmintrin.h:386
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_storeupd': C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\emmintrin.h:586
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_pavgb128': C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\emmintrin.h:671
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_pavgw128': C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\emmintrin.h:677
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_storedqu': C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\emmintrin.h:1177
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_storelv4si'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_storelps'?: C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\emmintrin.h:1189
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_movntpd'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_movntsd'?: C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\emmintrin.h:1195
ERROR: [HLS 214-124] use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_movntdq'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_movntq'?: C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\win64\tools\clang\lib\clang\3.1\include\emmintrin.h:1201
Wrong pragma usage.
```

**PS**: I know that using streams is a better way to the data transfer rather than using arrays, my objective is to implement a naive implementation using arrays and then optimize it using different pragmas like streams.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answers are probably very different for the 2 languages you tagged your question with. I suggest you tag the specific language you're compiling (looks like C++ with deprecated headers, though I do not know C++) --- C tag removed.

Comment: your function prototype for `ct_filter` doesn't match its definition. In the prototype (the function declaration in the header file), the 3rd argument is a singular `data_t input_image`. In the definition (where you actually define the function in the .cpp file), the 3rd argument is the array `data_t src[256][512][3]`. The compiler is rightly complaining these are two different types, and in fact two different functions.

Comment: @yano thanks for pointing it out, soved

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not designing the filter's architecture directly in HDL?

Comment: @eldesgraciado, yes my project requires it to be implemented using vivado hls. Also I understand that it's easy using vivado hls, as it's a high level language

Answer (score 2):

by removing the below mentioned libraries

```
//#include <windows.h>
//#include <windef.h>
```

the conflict was resolved